# Pyramid patterns using C

Tags: c

I need to do the following pattern using do-while, while or for.

[image]

I tried the following code but it prints the pattern only 1-5
I also tried to alter the n being 10 but then the spacing goes nuts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  int n = 5, i, j, num = 1, gap;


  gap = n - 1;

  for ( j = 1 ; j <= n ; j++ )
  {
      num = j;

      for ( i = 1 ; i <= gap ; i++ )
          printf(" ");

      gap --;

      for ( i = 1 ; i <= j ; i++ )
      {
          printf("%d", num);
          num++;
      }
      num--;
      num--;
      for ( i = 1 ; i < j ; i++)
      {
          printf("%d", num);
          num--;
      }
      printf("\n");

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing both occurences of:

`printf("%d", num);`

with

`printf("%d", num % 10);`

Now only the last digit will be shown.

After the change, for `n` set to `10` the program produces:

```
         1
        232
       34543
      4567654
     567898765
    67890109876
   7890123210987
  890123454321098
 90123456765432109
0123456789876543210
```